# How to plot a variable over time with time as rownames

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a time series in ggplot2. Assume I am using the following data structure (2500 x 20 matrix):

```
set.seed(21)

n <- 2500
x <- matrix(replicate(20,cumsum(sample(c(-1, 1), n, TRUE))),nrow = 2500,ncol=20)

aa <- x

rnames <- seq(as.Date("2010-01-01"), length=dim(aa)[1], by="1 month") - 1
rownames(aa) <- format(as.POSIXlt(rnames, format = "%Y-%m-%d"), format = "%d.%m.%Y")
colnames(aa) <- paste0("aa",1:k)

library("ggplot2")
library("reshape2")
library("scales")

aa <- melt(aa, id.vars = rownames(aa))
names(aa) <- c("time","id","value")
```

Now the following command to plot the time series produces a weird looking x axis:

```
ggplot(aa, aes(x=time,y=value,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_line()
```

What I found out is that I can change the format to date:

```
aa$time <- as.Date(aa$time, "%d.%m.%Y")
ggplot(aa, aes(x=time,y=value,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_line()
```

This looks better, but still not a good graph. My question is especially how to control the formatting of the x axis.
Does it have to be in `Date` format? How can I control the amount of breaks (i.e. years) shown in either case? It seems to be mandatory if `Date` is not used; otherwise ggplot2 uses some kind of useful default for the breaks I believe.
For example the following command does not work:

```
aa$time <- as.Date(aa$time, "%d.%m.%Y")
ggplot(aa, aes(x=time,y=value,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=pretty_breaks(n=10))
```

Also if you got any hints how to improve the overall look of the graph feel free to add (e.g. the lines look a bit inprecise imho).

Comment: Can you perhaps post a minimal example with sample input data and expected output? Try `?scale_date` and within it `scale_x_date` perhaps?

Comment: @Gopala What do you mean? I provided a MWE above? Well for a start the axis doesn't show any breaks at all if I used `ggplot(aa, aes(x=time,y=value,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_line()`, that is without the date format. I was wondering how to control the x-axis properly, also in cases where I do not have time there but another variable instead. However I think for this particular case it's easiest to work with the date format.

Comment: Sorry, I did not mean that you did not provide. It seems like your problem/question is lot simpler than the code you provided. I was thinking an even smaller example would suffice. Yeah, working with dates and using `scale_date` seems like a good thing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can format dates with `scale_x_date` as @Gopala mentioned. Here's an example using a shortened version of your data for illustration.

```
library(dplyr)

# Dates need to be in date format
aa$time <- as.Date(aa$time, "%d.%m.%Y")

# Shorten data to speed rendering
aa = aa %>% group_by(id) %>% slice(1:200)
```

In the code below, we get date breaks every six months with `date_breaks="6 months"`. That's probably more breaks than you want in this case and is just for illustration. If you want to determine which months get the breaks (e.g., Jan/July, Feb/Aug, etc.) then you also need to use `coord_cartesian` and set the start date with `xlim` and `expand=FALSE` so that ggplot won't pad the start date. But when you set `expand=FALSE` you also don't get any padding on the y-axis, so you need to add the padding manually with `scale_y_continuous` (I'd prefer to be able to set `expand` separately for the x and y axes, but AFAIK it's not possible). Because the breaks are packed tightly, we use a `theme` statement to rotate the labels by 90 degrees.

```
ggplot(aa, aes(x=time,y=value,colour=id,group=id)) + 
  geom_line(show.legend=FALSE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(min(aa$value) - 2, max(aa$value) + 1)) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks="6 months", 
               labels=function(d) format(d, "%b %Y")) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(as.Date("2009-07-01"), max(aa$time) + 182), 
                  expand=FALSE) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]